# Call to a member function on a non-object with mysqli

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm starting to learn how to use OOP within PHP and so far I want to create a Database class that looks like this:

```
class Database{
  //Database connection variables
  private $DBHost = "localhost";
  private $DBUser = "username";
  private $DBPass = "password";
  private $DBName = "database3";
  public $DBCon;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->DBCon = new mysqli($this->DBHost,$this->DBUser,$this->DBPass,$this->DBName);
  }

  public function con(){
    return $this->DBCon;
  }

  public function __destruct(){
    $this->DBCon->close();
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to interact with that class from another one called Application:

```
include('Database.php');
class Application{
  public $DB;

  public function __construct() {
    $DB = new Database();
  }

  public function InsertName($Username){
  var_dump($this->DB->con());
    if($this->DB->con()->query("INSERT INTO Test (name) VALUES ($Username);") === TRUE){
      echo "Okay";
    }else{
      echo "Error";
    }
  }
}
```

But I get the error `Call to a member function con() on a non-object`

As a side note, is this an appropriate way to interact with a database in OOP?

Comment: Instead of `$this->DB->con()->query` try `$this->DB->query` or `$DB->query` .Please check once both and tell it's working or not?

Comment: Inside your Application class constructor, you are using `$DB = new Database();` . It should be `$this->DB = new Database();` so you can access it later in your insert function.

Comment: @Adon nailed it, the construct is implemented wrong. DB is saved as a local variable in the __construct instead of an instance variable

Comment: You also don't seem to have a way of passing connection details to the `Database` constructor. How do you set, for example, `DBHost`?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Application class constructor, `$DB` is being assigned `new Database()`.

This variable is considered a local variable in this case with its scope being the constructor function itself.

To properly assign the new database object to the `public $DB` property, you will need to access it via the object's `$this` reference.

`public function __construct() {
    $this->DB = new Database();
  }`

This way you will be able to access the proper assigned public property throughout your remaining class methods.

Comment: correct. his problem is that the `$DB` variable stays uninitialized, and not a mysqli instance.